# Extract data from another workbook using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am busy creating my own function in VBA to extract data from another workbook in the same directory. However, when I call it as a function from within the destination workbook (Workbook A), it gives me a `VALUE!#` error. When I call the function from within a sub procedure where I test my code, it successfully extracts the correct data.

Within Excel I call my function like this `=CALCULATE_METERS("D1")`, and to test it using the sub procedure I call it like this from within the same module:

```
Sub test()
  CALCULATE_METERS ("D1")
  CALCULATE_METERS ("D1,2")
  CALCULATE_METERS ("D1-3")
  CALCULATE_METERS ("D1-5,8,9")
  CALCULATE_METERS ("D1(2),4(2),23(1),24-28")
  CALCULATE_METERS ("D1,4(2),23-25,26-28(2);E1-4;A1-2")
End Sub
```

The function containing the VLOOKUP code is (this is called within the `CALCULATE_METERS` function):

```
Private Function GetSquareMeters(block As String, r As Integer) As Integer
  Dim result As String
  Dim meters As String
  Dim wrkb As Workbook
  Dim wrks As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim directory As String
  Dim filename As String
  filename = "DATA REFERENCE.xlsx"
  directory = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  filename = directory & "\" & filename
  Debug.Print (filename)

  Set wrkb = Workbooks.Open(filename)

  meters = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(block, wrkb.Worksheets("Lande").Range("$A$2:$F$120"), 5)

  GetSquareMeters = CInt(meters) * r / 7
End Function
```

Everything prints in the immediate window up until the `filename` in the above function, but I believe the value error is generated on the lookup function. Why is it that calling the same function with the same arguments (one within excel, the other one within a sub procedure) gives different answers? How can I correct this so that I can use the function within an Excel cell?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to open the same workbook over and over and over again ???

Comment: @Gary'sStudent sorry if it is a noob question, I am very new to VBA and excel in general. I would ideally not like to open the workbook at all, I just need to find and extract the data. I have really been struggling to find a solution to this problem so this is the code I have at the moment. A solution similar to the simple VLOOKUP function inside a worksheet cell would be ideal, but I need to be able to parse the string before doing a lookup since a cell could contain many values. Thats why I moved it to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Find isntead of VLookup:

```
Function GetSquareMeters(block As String, r As Integer) As Integer
  Dim result As String
  Dim meters As String
  Dim wrkb As Workbook
  Dim wrks As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim directory As String
  Dim filename As String
  filename = "DATA REFERENCE.xlsx"
  directory = ActiveWorkbook.Path
  filename = directory & "\" & filename
  Debug.Print (filename)

 For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.FullName = Filename Then
    Set wrkb = Workbooks(Filename)
    Else
    Set wrkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename)
    End If
 Next

    meters = wrkb.Sheets("Lande").Range("$A$2:$F$120").Find(block).Offset(0, 4).Value

  GetSquareMeters = CInt(meters) * r / 7
End Function
```

Comment: I am still getting the same value error when I implement this.

Comment: Check if your "block" and "r" is correct type 
"Block" - text, "r" - whole number. For me works fine

Comment: Okay, it works if I use `.Offset(0,4)` to get the equivalent column of the VLOOKUP function. But this only works when I run the module in the VBA editor. I would actually like to call it as a function in the excel sheet. In this case it still gives me an error. Does not seem like the source workbook is opened when I call the function by typing `=CALCULATE_METERS("D1")` in a cell. And I would ideally not like to open the source notebook `DATA REFERENCE.xlsx` if possible.

Comment: make function non private and remove all references to workbooks, eg
[_Dim directory As String
  Dim filename As String
  filename = "DATA REFERENCE.xlsx"
  directory = ActiveWorkbook.Path_]